# How to use VBA autofilter with wildcards on both strings and numbers?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, wildcard, autofilter

I am using the autofilter function in VBA to filter an excel sheet. Below is a picture of a piece of the table.

[image]

The code below executes when a users makes a change to a text box on the same worksheet. The issue I am having is that any cell that contains only a number (such as 2084) is filtered out due to my use of wildcards in the filter. The filter works fine on cells that contain letters. How would I go about converting the numeric cells to strings such that my filter would catch 2084 if the users enters "20" in the text box?

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Dim Txt As String
    Dim rng As Range

    Txt = TextBox2.Text
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("a13:a1000")
    If Len(Txt) > 0 Then
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & Txt & "*"
    Else
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & Txt
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't test this out and not sure how it would work, but what if you did `CStr(txt)`?

Comment: I just test the codes. It is working fine. No error, it is catching 20... Do you formatted `Column A` as text? If not, then it will not catch ...20...

Comment: @BYates That would only cast the users text box entry to a string, not the cells being searched. I tried anyway and no change.

Comment: @harun24hr The first thing I tried was formatting the cells as text, but it does not work for me. If I use isNumeric(cell#), it returns true even though I changed the cell to text.

Comment: @JohnnyW for testing purpose, take a new sheet. Format `Column A` as text then entry data and run your code. I think it will work as it work to me.

Comment: @harun24hr Looks like you were sort of correct. It was a copy paste issue. I was not able to copy paste then change the cell formatting to text for some reason. I had to define the cell as text, then enter the data. Luckily the table is not that large yet so it wasn't too hard to fix. Thanks for your suggestion, it got me on the right track!

Comment: `Criteria1:="=*" & ThresholdOLFilterStr & "*"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind off on the same path but I want to avoid formatting data as text (cause some data might be a formula result and I want to keep the formula).

Meanwhile, I achieved what you need to do and a bit more: I formatted the cells to text, filtered and formatted back to numbers the cells that were originally numbers.

Beware: [IsNumeric()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) returns

> (...) a Boolean value indicating whether an expression **can be evaluated** as a number

That's why IsNumeric() returned True even when you formatted numbers as text. You may use [Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber) instead, that

> checks the type of value and returns True or False depending on whether the value refers to a number.

I use both in the example below for different purposes:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Dim Txt As String, rng As Range, rowCount as Long

    Txt = TextBox2.Text
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("a13:a1000")
    rowCount = rng.Rows.Count
'    This one is for saving if they were originally numbers:
    ReDim isNumberArray(1 To rowCount) As Boolean

    If Len(Txt) > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To rowCount
'           I use IsNumber here cause I only care for cells with actual
'            number format
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(rng(i, 1)) Then
'                Format numbers as text and save their original format as a
'                  Boolean in IsNumberArray using their index
                rng(i, 1) = "'" & (rng(i, 1))
                isNumberArray(i) = True
            Else
                isNumberArray(i) = False
            End If
        Next i

        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & Txt & "*"
        For i = 1 To rowCount
'            I use IsNumeric here because they are all in text format
'             but some may be evaluated as numbers. IsNumber woould be
'             false for all instances.
'            The sentence rng(i, 1) <> "" is there because IsNumeric()
'             is also True for Empty cells.
            If IsNumeric(rng(i, 1)) And rng(i, 1) <> "" And numberArray(i) Then
                rng(i, 1) = CDbl(rng(i, 1))
            End If
        Next i

    Else
'    This removes filter
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1
    End If
 End Sub
```

With my problem, I guess I can store the formula instead of the data format and retrieve it. It gets worse cause I have array formulas but will see what I can do. Hope this helps someone out.